# Version higher to Spring2.0.6.jar

Tags: spring, maven

I am currently using Spring2.0.6.jar, but I am getting an error while using it. Without this jar few applications are running successfully but few applications are not.

So is there a jar which supports Spring 3?

Comment: @Ralph is there a jar of higher version, i.e, higher than spring2.0.6.jar?

Comment: The answer I wanted was a higher version of Spring2.0.6.jar.. I have got the answer below. I am right now using Spring2.5.6.jar as suggested by NimChimpsky. I don't see why this is not a real question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring

Up to version 2.5.6 now
[min chars]

Comment: You have guided me right once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is

- Spring 2.5.x
- Spring 3.0.x,
- Spring 3.1.x, and
- Spring 3.2.0.Milestones.

http://www.springsource.org/download/community

Comment: I already downloaded this whole thing you have mentioned but found no jar equivalent to spring2.0.6.jar. So can you please be specific to point the equivalent jar in the higher version? It will be very helpful for me, if the jar is of version 3.x...

Comment: So your are looking for the "spring all in one jar"?